# Android Flash Detection

Tags: android

I am trying to find out whether flash led exist or not on my device. My code is like below;

```
flashExists = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if(flashExists)
    {
        do something;
    }
    else
    {
        do something else;
    }
```

I have three test devices, a phone without any flash (samsung galaxy s), a phone with a flash (nexus 5), a tablet with flash (samsung galaxy note 10.1).

Unfortunately, code always returns true, so, for galaxy s, I am unable to execute desired code block. Am I missing something here or Samsung Galaxy S requires something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [flash modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFlashMode%28%29) of the `Camera`, check if the `List` empty or null or `FLASH_MODE_OFF`

Comment: I believe, flash_mode_off is an expected situation but I will definitely try to check if the list empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, problem only stands for Samsung Galaxy S, so, I have added an exception for that device;

```
if(!flashExists || android.os.Build.MODEL.equalsIgnoreCase("GT-I9000"))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else

    }
```